# Under what conditions to have $ (b+1)^n \bmod 2b = (b+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Under What conditions, for any integer $n \geq 1$, we will have:

$$ (b+1)^n \bmod 2b = (b+1)$$

I tested it with a couple of numbers, and it is true for $3, 5, 7$, etc.

Please prove your theory.

[It is based on a comment of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62126/proof-that-6n-always-has-a-last-digit-of-6/62133#62133)

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the congruence $(b+1)^n\equiv(b+1)$? For starters, what might you do with the equation $x^n=x$, for example? Have you tested enough numbers to form a hypothesis? Once you have a hypothesis, you might be able to prove it.

Comment: Note that my answer there says it is true for odd $\,b\,$ since the proof is the same as the special case: $ $ it is true mod $2$ and $\,b\,$ so mod their lcm [recall $\,x^n\equiv x\pmod 2\,$] $\ \ $

Comment: For any $n$. I tested for $b=3,5,7$

Comment: By the way, should we write $6^n \bmod 10 = 6$ or $6^n = 6 ( \bmod 10)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For $b$ odd**,  $b=2k+1$ and $$b^2=b(2k+1)=2b\cdot k+b \equiv b \bmod (2b)$$

Now $$(b+1)^2 = b^2+2b+1 \equiv b^2+1 \equiv (b+1) \bmod (2b)$$ as required.

Then given $(b+1)^k \equiv (b+1)\bmod(2k)$,
 clearly $(b+1)^{k+1} = (b+1)^k(b+1) \equiv (b+1)(b+1) \equiv (b+1) \bmod (2b)$,
 and the result holds for all $n$.

**For $b$ even**, $b=2k$, $b^2 \equiv 0 \bmod (2b)$ and $(b+1)^2 \equiv 1 \bmod (2b)$,
so the original requirement does not hold.

---

Note that with even $b$ and odd $n$, the original condition will hold, since all even powers of $(b+1)$ will reduce to $1 \bmod (2b)$ So we could say: 
$$ (b+1)^n \equiv (b+1) \bmod (2b) \qquad \text{whenever }b\text{ or }n\text{ odd}$$

---

We can also make some observations on $(b-1)^n \bmod (2b)$. For odd $b$, powers of $(b-1)$ alternate between $(b+1)$ and $(b-1) \bmod (2b)$, and for even $b$, powers of $(b-1)$ alternate between $1$ and $(b-1) \bmod (2b)$. So it turns out that 
$$(b-1)^n \equiv (b-1) \bmod (2b) \qquad \text{for }n\text{ odd}$$

Comment: Sorry. I see it. Thanks. By the way, do we say $36 \bmod 10 = 6$ or your way?

Comment: If I'm using $\bmod$ as a function in that way,  I would probably bracket it: $(36 \bmod 10) = 6$. Most of the time I use $\equiv$(\equiv) and $\bmod n$ after.

Comment: I voted, but I think induction method needs to be used to show for k and k+1, after k=2. It should be true for $b$ is odd.

Comment: @PdotWang formalized the induction.